# High DPI screenshot in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a little application that would take screenshots of the Windows desktop.
Now i've got this code which is pretty classic :

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot() As Bitmap

    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)
    screenGrab.SetResolution(2400, 2400)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)

    Return screenGrab

End Function
```

But I'd like to have a very good quality screenshot. I don't know if it is possible, so I'm asking, but could I maybe get a higher resolution screenshot by modifying the DPI (like I did) or maybe by increasing the initial size of the bitmap ? I don't know at all so I ask...

Thank you in advance

Comment: How would someone raise the quality of a screenshot? You can only get it as seen on screen. What's wrong with the current quality?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking ! But I was thinking about the fact that I think (it's a supposition once again) that everything is pretty high resolution or even vectorial in Windows, so it could maybe be more precise, but I don't know how !

Comment: People should trust less the movies where they zoom into a CCTV image to see a reflection of the killer in one of the shiny screw heads...

Comment: Ahaha you're funny x) it's not a photo that I want to zoom in... But anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Pixels are something like the atoms of computer graphics.

You can't go deeper.

(Yes I know we actually can in the real world or in some hollywood movies with Leonardo DiCaprio, but let's just say atoms are the smallest possible unit. This isn't Physics Exchange, and for a reason I don't have an account there ;S).

Comment: OK thanks I see. I now have the confirmation that is not possible at all. Thanks again :)